# How to create a ReactiveSearch hierarchical checkbox menu?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

Using the Reactive Search UI Kit how can i create hierarchical menu looking like this (but with the traditional checkbox):

[image]

This component would take data from ES index with records looking like this :

```
country: "China",
cities: ["Guangzhou","Shanghai","Chongqing"]

country: "India",
cities: ["Mumbai","Delhi","Bangalore"]
```

I am trying to show cities only when the country is "selected". And users could select cities in multiple countries.

Thanx

Comment: This is an open issue currently https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/167. Would be great if you can post your use case there :)

Comment: Thank you ! I added the use case